# sencha app build production WRN C1014: callParent has no target

Tags: extjs

sencha app build production

WRN C1014: callParent has no target
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I updated sencha cmd with `sencha upgrade`, then my app with `sencha app upgrade` and the warnings are gone.